# Clique em botão executa uma ação segundo clique no mesmo botão executa ação diferente

Tags: android

Preciso saber como um primeiro clique no botão executa uma ação, um segundo clique no mesmo botão executa uma ação diferente

Seria possível isso?

Eu tentei:
Mas não deu muito certo não.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        myLayout.setVisibily(View.VISIBLE);
        if (myLayout.isShown()){
            myLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o que você pretende é que o botão mude a visibilidade da *view* em cada *click*, alternado de visível para invisível pode fazer assim:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(myLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            myLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            myLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

O seu código andava perto, o problema é que *"setava"* primeiro a visibilidade antes do teste o que fazia que este fosse sempre *true*.
Altere-o para:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){

        if (myLayout.isShown()){
            myLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            myLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Note que `view.isShown()` não é equivalente `view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE`. 
`view.isShown()` não só verifica a visibilidade da *view* mas também a de todos os seus *"ancestors "*.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível.

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {

    /**
    * @Variável: hasClicked
    * @Tipo: booleana
    * @Descrição: Para verificarmos se algum toque foi feito no botão, poderemos usar uma variável do tipo Booleana.
    *   Se você precisa verificar se apenas 1 toque foi feito, este tipo de variável pode ser usada. Caso contrário, teremos que usar um outro tipo.
    */

    Boolean hasClicked;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle cicle) {
        super.onCreate(cicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /**
        * Injetar onClickListener no seu botão desejado.
        */

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_click)).setOnClickListener(handler);

    }

    View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /**
            *    @função: isto, primeiramente, vai verificar se a variável hasClicked é falsa, se sim, vai executar sua primeira função.
            *  Se for verdadeira, ela vai executar sua segunda função....
            */
            if(!hasClicked) {
                hasClicked = true;
                // Executar primeira função
            } else { 
                // Executar segunda função
            }
        }
    }
}
```